# Grails constraints for Latin letters

Tags: validation, grails, latin

I am using grails contraints mechanism to validate on a **"name"** field. How can I use `regex` to specify that, not only this should be allowed: `matches:"[a-zA-z0-9_]+"`, but also characters like: `ã, ó, ç, â, é,` etc. (Brasilian characters)

Answer (score 1):

For Latin/UTF-8 characters use: `[\p{L}\p{Digit}_]+`

For more info, check the [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) javadocs.